# Bootstrap Progress bar with custom validation

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to activate the tabs of progress bar only after slight validations. However, the CSS % property of progress bar fails to change. Here is my Javascript relevant code and [working code on FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3g53ze1h/1/):

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {

    console.log("here");
    //update progress
    var step = $(e.target).data('step');
    var percent = (parseInt(step) / 4) * 100;

    $('.progress-bar').css({width: percent + '%'});
    $('.progress-bar').text(percent + '%');

    //e.relatedTarget // previous tab

})
$('#page-wrapper').on('click', '#to-tab-2', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

        $('ul.nav-pills li a[data-step="2"]').attr({
            "href": "#step2",
            "data-toggle": "tab"
        });
        $('a[href="#step2"]').parent().removeClass('disabled')
        $('a[href="#step2"]').click();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>You mispelled `tab` in `data-toggle="tabe"`. This should work :</s>

<s>>[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/52uduhgs/)</s>

---

EDIT :

Your selector for your tabs should be `$('.nav.nav-pills').on('shown.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) {});`. The CSS is working, just click event isn't triggered because of the change of the `data-toggle` value.

This way, it will work as intended.

> [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nfe8qm6h/)

Comment: I haven't misspelt it. I want to disable the tab navigation, hence I've change it to `tabe`. On successful validation, I change it back to `tab`. Please refer my code.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I didn't understood what was the matter. Please see the edit.

Comment: Wellcome, and sorry for rushing :S